# How to display custom object properties in View page using ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, controller

I am trying to add ASP.NET MVC features (especially routing) to my already existing ASP.NET web application. I added a Controller and View (an asp.net page).

Now I want to know how can I display the details of object of my custom class (for example, User) in the view? Can I assign the object in ViewData collection and render it in the view? I already have a Datalayer (in ADO.NET) which is running for the the current ASP.NET web app, so I want to use that.

I tried this in my controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        BusinessObject.User objUser = new BusinessObject.User();
        objUser.EmailId = "shyju@company.com";
        objUser.ProfileTitle = "Web developer with 6 yrs expereince";

        ViewData["objUser"] = objUser;
        ViewData["Message"] = "This is ASP.NET MVC!";

        return View();
    }
```

How can I use this in the view page to display the user details ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass your object as a view model (or part of a view model, along with your message) to a strongly-typed view.  Then you can simply reference the model properties in your view.

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    public BusinessObject.User User { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

(or, better yet, just the properties from the user object that you really need)

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    BusinessObject.User objUser = new BusinessObject.User();
    objUser.EmailId = "shyju@company.com";
    objUser.ProfileTitle = "Web developer with 6 yrs expereince";

    return View( new IndexViewModel {
         User = objUser,
         Message = "This is ASP.NET MVC!";
    });
}
```

View

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#"
    MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master"
    Inherits="System.Web.MVC.ViewPage<MyWebSite.Models.IndexViewModel>" %>

<%= Html.Encode( Model.User.EmailId ) %>
```

Comment: What does this Inherits="System.Web.MVC.ViewPage<MyWebSite.Models.IndexViewModel>"  means ?

Comment: @shyju - It means that the ViewPage's Model property is of type `MyWebSite.Models.IndexViewModel` -- the namespace is fake, but is meant to correpsond with the model class in the example.